# Nextjs 11 new use of import keyword for image 'src' throwing error CompileError: mutable globals cannot be exported

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nextjs-image, wasm-pack

I recently upgraded to nextjs 11 and used their new image feature where you can import your images and use them in the src attribute as follows:

```
import mallImage from '../public/images/ads/mall.png';
```

then use can use it as

```
<Image src={mallImage} alt="image of person" />
```

it was working fine, till it started to throw the error

```
./public/images/ads/mall.png
CompileError: AsyncCompile: Wasm decoding failed: mutable globals cannot be exported @+482
```

I am so confused because I am using it exactly how it is used in the documentation
https://nextjs.org/blog/next-11#image-improvements

THIS BUG SEEMS TO ONLY BE HAPPENING ON THE DEV SERVER

Comment: You don't need to refer to public folder.Next does it for you.Use just `import mallImage from '../images/ads/mall.png';`

Comment: that didn't work, it gave `Module not found: Can't resolve '../images/ads/mall.png'` because it is trying to import the image like how react normally does

Comment: This should work `import mallImage from 'images/ads/mall.png';`

Comment: @Randall that didn't work either

Comment: Not sure about `wasm-pack`, but this thing works just fine in the create-next-app (webpack) configuration. @Randall One **needs** to reference the public folder while importing. One doesn't need it if they are using a string as src, in that case `/images/ads/mall.png` would have been sufficient but that doesn't work with  the new static image feature (automatic height/width deduction & `placeholder=blur` without providing `blurDataURL`).

Comment: @brc-dd exactly, this bug seems to only be happening in the dev server `yarn dev`

Comment: @Damiisdandy I see you have created an issue for this on the Next.js repository, but I don't think that they will be able to reproduce this unless you provide them with a minimal reproducible example (possibly in the form of a repository) as the issue occurs specifically with `wasm-pack` and not in general.

Comment: @brc-dd it's a private repository

Comment: @Damiisdandy Yeah I understand that, I am not asking you to share confidential code. Just create a repository and put the least code required to get this error. No need to put anything other than that. Just dummy components and placeholder images. No secret configurations required. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @brc-dd, I fixed the issue by changing the images, the previous images were exported from photoshop's **quick export png**, then I compressed it with https://tinypng.com, maybe the images got reconstructed in a certain way, but now it's working fine because I converted it to jpg

Comment: I am getting the exact same issue.   I get the issue when building my application.  I have tried lots of different things, i have tried putting the filename directly in the Image tag, i have tried importing the image and adding the object in the Image tag, I have tried the img tag.  Nothing is working.  I can not recreate my images as they were provided to me by my UX team

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Do not import like react. and try this

```
<Image src={"/images/ads/mall.png"} alt="image of person" layout={"fill"} />
```

or

```
<Image src={"/images/ads/mall.png"} alt="image of person" width={100} height={100} />
```